# how to get string removing parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am getting string from json dictionory but result string is in brackets, i have to get string without backets

code is

```
jsonDictionary  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];        
NSDictionary *dictResult = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"result"];
NSDictionary *dictPronunciations = [dictResult valueForKey:@"pronunciations"];
NSDictionary *dictAudio = [dictPronunciations valueForKey:@"audio"];
NSString *strMp3Path = [dictAudio valueForKey:@"url"];
NSLog(@"str mp3 path %@",strMp3Path);
```

and  result is

```
(
    (
        "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/abate0205.mp3"
    )
)
```

I want to get `/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/abate0205.mp3`  as a string without brackets. Please help...

Comment: stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following code:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [dictAudio valueForKey:@"url"];
NSString *myStr = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", myStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The object you are logging is not a NSString instance. it is a string inside an array in an array.

try:

```
NSLog(@"str mp3 path %@",strMp3Path[0][0]);
```

if this prints as desired, the object `dictAudio` holds with the key `url` is an array, with an array. you should fix that where ever you stick it into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. If your values are multiple from json then the value can be added one by one without braces :

```
NSMutableArray *dictPronunciations = [dictResult valueForKey:@"pronunciations"];

NSMutableArray *arrayPronunciations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i< [dictPronunciations count]; i++)
                 {
                     NSString *string = [dictPronunciations objectAtIndex:i];

                     NSLog(@"String = %@",string);

                     [arrayPronunciations addObject:string];
                 }

NSLog(@"Array Pronounciations = %@",arrayPronunciations);
```